# How do I append to each line of a .txt file using cmd across multiple files

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, windows-7

I have a large amount of .txt files residing in a single directory that have contents resembling the following...

file1.txt

```
ABCDEFG
HIJKLMN
OPQRSTU
```

file2.txt

```
EIQOQAL
JFAIWLA
AWIALAJ
```

I want to copy the contents across all of the files into a single file and append the file name to each line. For example...

Result.txt

```
ABCDEFG,file1.txt
HIJKLMN,file1.txt
OPQRSTU,file1.txt
EIQOQAL,file2.txt
JFAIWLA,file2.txt
AWIALAJ,file2.txt
```

Can this be done using Windows .bat commands? Thanks in advance!
-Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested.

```
break>united.txt
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%~fa") do (
        (echo(%%#,%%~nxa)>>united.txt
   )
)
```